# How to do: elements: this.buildElements(0, 20)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How would you do the following in ES6:

```
getInitialState: function() {
    return {
        elements: this.buildElements(0, 20),
        isInfiniteLoading: false
    }
},
```

Tried this:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = { isInfiniteLoading: false };
  this.elements = this.buildElements(0, 20);
}
```

This just gives: "Uncaught ReferenceError: elements is not defined"

Comment: Where is `buildElements` declared? What is the problem you're trying to solve? Where does it throw that error, you're not accessing `elements` in the code you've shown us?

Comment: In the first example, `elements` and `isInfiniteLoading` both live on `state` and in the second example, one is in `state` and one is on the component directly. What are you expecting?

Answer (score 1):

loganfsmyth led me to the answer.

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = { isInfiniteLoading: false , elements: this.buildElements(0, 20)};
}
```